# How to reset power on password Lenovo AIO C240

Tags: bios, passwords, thinkpad

I need to reset **`power on password`** or setup password on the **`BIOS`** for a **`Lenovo AIO C240`**.
I tried a lot of things but nothing works. For example:

1. Power off the computer.
2. Disconnect AC adapter (if it's connected).
3. Take off the battery (3v). (I take off ram memory too)
4. Press and hold power button several time for several seconds each time.
5. Release power button.
6. Put in back the battery and reconnect AC.
7. Power on.

I couldn't find any jumper to clear cmos on the motherboard. I wasted a lot of days trying everything I found in Internet but I couldn't solve it!

**`Is there any solution for this?`** Please help me!... 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you contacted Lenovo support?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bypass Lenovo Thinkpad power-on password?](http://superuser.com/questions/284231/how-to-bypass-lenovo-thinkpad-power-on-password)

Comment: @DaveM, yes I called Lenovo support but my computer is out of warranty. I going to call them again and try to find a solution.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I read that thread but I couldn't find any solution there. Yes I think I have a similar trouble, but my computer is a All In One (AIO) and I thought could someone had solved this problem.

Comment: It's the same problem (IMO).  The Lenovo AIOs are (basically) just laptops shoved into a thin case with a monitor, so the answer(s) are the same: 1) Look in the repair manual for instructions to try to short the CMOS clear (if there is one).  2) Contact Lenovo and ask them what you need to do, or if it's even possible, as it may require a trip to a Lenovo repair depot to be reset.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes you are right The Lenovo AIOs are just like laptops, I'm going to do that, thank for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Cutting off the power for your motherboard (including battery removal) will not work in this case. The main problem is that the password is stored on EEPROM/flash memory. Some unlocks are made by computer vendors basing on RTC time and scan of an invoice of your device. They generate a master password and send you back. I do not know if this can be done that way for Lenovo. If not - well - you might have some troubles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I read this [Why is my BIOS power-on password not resetting even though my CMOS battery?](https://superuser.com/questions/620698/why-is-my-bios-power-on-password-not-resetting-even-though-my-cmos-battery-has-b)... I think my Lenovo AIO C240 comes with a [TPM (Trusted Platform Module)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module), the TPM stores things like the BIOS password. No amount of removing the battery or doing motherboard jumpers will unlock the BIOS password screen...but I'm not sure...